# ¿Como sumar 2 variables dentro de un JSON obtenidas de un Web services en angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, json

Tengo una gran duda, hoy me encuentro consumiendo datos de un web services como siempre, utilizando angularJS y se me presento un nuevo problema:

Consumo un web services que como respuesta me da lo siguiente:

```
{success: "true", n_sucursales: 2, id_sucursal: "19", id_servicio: "38,39",…}
activo_modulos:"1,1"
id_modulos:"18,52"
id_servicio:"38,39"
id_sucursal:"19"
n_modulos:2
n_sucursales: 2
nombre_modulos: "1 - Farmacia Preferencial,2 - Farmacia Preferencial"
nombre_servicio: "NORMAL,PREFERENCIAL"
nombre_sucursal:"Hospital Sótero"
success:"true"
```

Si se dan cuenta hay variables que me traen dos datos, en este caso me enfoco en `ID_SERVICIO` porque tengo que enviar esos datos a otro web services.

Cómo los mando: primero configuro url, method, etc. en un servicio y luego los datos obtenidos los guardo en una variable y finalmente los mando así (me gustaría hacer 1 sola petición):

```js
//consume los datos de id_servicio 38 [NORMAL]
Conection.Colaservices({
        id_servicio: SaveCredentials.getData().id_servicio.split(',')[0]
    },
    function(response) {
        console.log('normal', JSON.stringify(response.data));
        $scope.normal = response.data;
    });

//consume los datos de id_servicio 39 [PREFERENCIAL]
Conection.Colaservices({
        id_servicio: SaveCredentials.getData().id_servicio.split(',')[1]
    },
    function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        $scope.preferencial = response.data;
    });
```

Teniendo como resultado:

```
//NORMAL : 38
{success: "true",…}
data:
    {id_servicio: "38", personas_esperando: "1", personas_atendidas: "706", tiempo_espera: "0",…}

id_servicio:"38"
id_ticket:"0"
letra:"-"
numero:"0"
personas_atendidas:"706"
personas_esperando:"1"
rut:"-"
tiempo_espera:"0"
success:"true"

//PREFERENCIAL: 39
{success: "true",…}
data:
    {id_servicio: "39", personas_esperando: "0", personas_atendidas: "208", tiempo_espera: "0",…}

id_servicio:"39"
id_ticket:"0"
letra:"-"
numero:"0"
personas_atendidas:"208"
personas_esperando:"0"
rut:"-"tiempo_espera:"0"
success:"true"
```

Pregunta:
¿Como sumar `personas_atendidas`: "706" de `NORMAL` con personas_atendidas:"208" de `PREFERENCIAL` (es decir mostrar 914)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//consume los datos de id_servicio 38 [NORMAL] 

Conection.Colaservices({

   id_servicio: SaveCredentials.getData().id_servicio.split(',')[0]},

   function(response){

        //console.log('normal',JSON.stringify(response.data));

        $scope.normal = parseInt(response.data.personas_atendidas);
   }

});

//consume los datos de id_servicio 39 [PREFERENCIAL]

Conection.Colaservices({

    id_servicio: SaveCredentials.getData().id_servicio.split(',')[1]},

    function(response){

          //console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));

          $scope.preferencial = parseInt(response.data.personas_atendidas);
    }
});

...

//codigo

$scope.personas_atendidas = $scope.normal + $scope.preferencial;
```

Comment: angular.js:13920 ReferenceError: parse is not defined
    at main.js:45
    at angular-resource.js:821
    at processQueue (angular.js:16383)
    at angular.js:16399
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17682)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17495)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17790)
    at done (angular.js:11831)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:12033)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:11966)   me sale ese error :o

Comment: Lo siento, estaba desarrollando para Windows 10 y se me cruzaron los métodos xD. Ya está corregido.